# Does firebase_crashlytics work when using try / catch in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-crash-reporting

If use try / catch my application will not crash. But I want when the catch block to work, it also sends error information to firebase crashlytics console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think solution are

- `Crashlytics.instance.log` for log Single message, string.
- `Crashlytics.instance.recordError` for log message error with stackTrace.
- `Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError` for log message is generated by flutter framework

Answer (score 2):

Inside the catch block send the error

```
catch(Exception e){
    Crashlytics.log(message);
    Crashlytics.logException(RunTimeExcption(message));
 }
```

Comment: I did not find the Crashlytics.log and the Crashlytics.logException function. but instead I found these 3 functions: Crashlytics.instance.log, Crashlytics.instance.recordError, Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError. I have not tried them yet. Do you have any experience using them?

Answer (score 2):

Because the app doesn't crash it won't show any errors in crashlytics but you can report it manually.

Comment: I have found these 3 functions: Crashlytics.instance.log, Crashlytics.instance.recordError, Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError. I have not tried them yet. Do you have any experience using them?